# How to create a Task which accept input arguments

Tags: c#, .net, task

I am struggling to create a Task which accepts some input arguments. Then later on, I want to start task with different values of input arguments. I am unable to find a nice way to create a task which accept input arguments and later on I can start it on demand.

I am trying following approach, however, while task creation, I have to supply input arguments and I do not want to provide input arguments at this point:

```
int [] intArray = new int [5] {1,2,3,4,5} ;
Task<double []> task1 = new Task<double []> (item => CovertToDoubleArray ((int []) item),  intArray) ;
```

Later on, I want to pass something else other than `intArray`. With this implementation `task1` is bound with `intArray`.

Comment: what you  mean by  input arguments

Comment: Why not just use `Func<>` or `Action<>` or a delegate to store which method to call, and then use `Task` to start it at the point where you have parameters?

Comment: @K.B: I want to pass intarray to ConvertToDoubleArra method

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: Please follow the answer of  "Ned Stoyanov". I am looking something similar and do not want to do it in a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your request correctly, you can try doing that with a generic method. When you want to create the task, simply call method.

```
public Task<double[]> ConvertToDouble<T>(T [] input)
{
    return new Task<double []> (CovertToDoubleArray ((T[]) item),  intArray) ;
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution as well. However, I am interested in something even smarter. Thanks.

Comment: @User1551892 simpler _is_ smarter.

Answer (score 2):

I highly doubt there's a workaround for your requirements.

If you could *not* supply the variables over which the lambda closes over when instantiating a task, then it would be possible to start a task that does not yet have the necessary data to run.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me that what you *actually* want is a *task factory* of some kind - maybe a `Func<SomeParamType, Task<SomeReturnType>>`. However, the operation you suggest in the post is simply **not** a great example of something that should involve a `Task`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several options available for you to create Tasks which accepts both Input and output:

1 : Use an action delegate with named method

```
var myTask = new Task(new Action(printSomething));
```

2 :  Use anonymous delegate

```
var myTask = new Task(delegate {printSomething();});
```

3 : Use lambda epx and method

```
var myTask = new Task(() => printSomething());
```

4 : Lambda and anonymous method

```
Task myTask = new Task(() => {printSomething();});
```

and you can have a method just like the following:

```
static void printSomething() {Console.WriteLine("I was passed to the Task");
```

Comment: what if I pass some input arguments to method "printSomthing( string atrb1)"